# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4 in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Android Studio version (3.0.1) and I installed Google Play Services and Google Repository

I tried using

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
```

in project gradle

this is my project grandle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my app build grandle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.congdong85.hn.hoangnguyen.doanungdungcast"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and I still get message when sync

> Error:(27, 20) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4

I can't sync com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.4 plase help me.

Comment: You're using a very old Android Studio, and very old versions of Firebase libraries.  I strongly suggesting updating everything.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

into this:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

You need to add the `google()` repo in the top level gradle file, as specified in the firebase docs and also it should be before `jcenter()`